# Android - No animation of RecyclerView when clearing adapter's data?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

Why is there no animation of the RecyclerView when I call the `clear()` method on the list of the data of the RecyclerView's adapter?

If there is an animation, then what is the proper way to clear the data of a RecyclerView with animation?

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have call `adapter.notifyItemRemoved()`or any others  after remove data in your List ?

`RecycleView` instantiates and uses an instance of `DefaultItemAnimator`,for more,you can see [recyclerview-animators](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators)

Comment: Yes I have. I tried `adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, adapter.getItemCount)` but it still doesn't show any animation.